# WordPress adding external URL to featured images

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add featured images while creating post. When user clicks on image it should get redirect to some external URL. I set custom field for redirect URL while creating post. But where to add the code in php file for redirection. While searching I found code

try and locate the line with `the_post_thumbnail()` in page.php, and add the link there;

example:

from:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

to:

```
<?php $name = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ExternalUrl', true);
if( $name ) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $name; ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
<?php } else {
the_post_thumbnail();
} ?>
```

But I didnt found `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>` in page.php or single.php . Is it right approach or any other alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default template then location the `content.php` file in your theme directory which serve the blog data to `index.php` file for display blog content.

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

This means your `content.php` file according to `twentytwelve` template. Hope this help you.